# XCode - creating archive fails with error «…-Prefix.pch» not found

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I have a workspace with multiple targets.

Each target has its own `prefix.pch` file.
Prefix-Header is entered in Build Settings and `Precompile Prefix Header` is set to YES.

The app compiles and runs fine when I run it on my device.
There are no errors when I just build the app.

But when I try to archive it, I get a compile error saying:

```
No such file or directory: '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-dcmvkatguqcxgjfyrqcunbsfuxcd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myAppTarget/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/13524936819627194222/myAppTarget-Prefix.pch'
```

And indeed, when I open this folder on my hd, I can't see the pch-file. There are, however, similar files there:

```
myAppTarget-Prefix.pch.d
myAppTarget-Prefix.pch.dia
myAppTarget-Prefix.pch.gch
```

I tried everything I found on SO and elsewhere, but nothing helped.

I have Cocoapods installed and use them in this project, but I don't think that error is related to that (they seem to compile fine).

XCode 12.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I figured it out.

The culprit was a totally unrelated build-setting.

In `Other C Flags` my settings differed in debug and release.
I had `$(inherited)` in both of them, but in the release setting I additionally had `-isystem` - which apparently is already included in `$(inherited)`. That caused a multitude of errors that ended with the prefix.pch not being copied...